# Why default 'mysql' database created using MyISAM engine instead of InnoDB?

Tags: mysql, linux

I am using `MySQL version 5.6` which has the default MySQL engine as InnoDB, that is if you don't specify an engine while creating tables, it is created using InnoDB.

But today, i noticed that the default `mysql` database is created using 'MyISAM' instead of InnoDB.

Any clue, why is it so?

```
Database changed
mysql> show tables;
+---------------------------+
| Tables_in_mysql           |
+---------------------------+
| columns_priv              |
| db                        |
| event                     |
| func                      |
| general_log               |
| help_category             |
| help_keyword              |
| help_relation             |
| help_topic                |
| innodb_index_stats        |
| innodb_table_stats        |
| ndb_binlog_index          |
| plugin                    |
| proc                      |
| procs_priv                |
| proxies_priv              |
| servers                   |
| slave_master_info         |
| slave_relay_log_info      |
| slave_worker_info         |
| slow_log                  |
| tables_priv               |
| time_zone                 |
| time_zone_leap_second     |
| time_zone_name            |
| time_zone_transition      |
| time_zone_transition_type |
| user                      |
+---------------------------+
28 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here is my cnf file:

```
# For advice on how to change settings please see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-configuration-defaults.html

[mysqld]
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
max_connections = 500
#
# Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data
# cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%.
# innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M
#
# Remove leading # to turn on a very important data integrity option: logging
# changes to the binary log between backups.
# log_bin
#
# Remove leading # to set options mainly useful for reporting servers.
# The server defaults are faster for transactions and fast SELECTs.
# Adjust sizes as needed, experiment to find the optimal values.
# join_buffer_size = 128M
# sort_buffer_size = 2M
# read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

# Recommended in standard MySQL setup
#sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Here is the mysqldump of one of these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `columns_priv` (
  `Host` char(60) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Db` char(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `User` char(16) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Table_name` char(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Column_name` char(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `Column_priv` set('Select','Insert','Update','References') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Host`,`Db`,`User`,`Table_name`,`Column_name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin COMMENT='Column privileges';


mysql> show engines;
+--------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| Engine             | Support | Comment                                                        | Transactions | XA   | Savepoints |
+--------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| MRG_MYISAM         | YES     | Collection of identical MyISAM tables                          | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| CSV                | YES     | CSV storage engine                                             | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MEMORY             | YES     | Hash based, stored in memory, useful for temporary tables      | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| BLACKHOLE          | YES     | /dev/null storage engine (anything you write to it disappears) | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MyISAM             | YES     | MyISAM storage engine                                          | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| FEDERATED          | NO      | Federated MySQL storage engine                                 | NULL         | NULL | NULL       |
| ARCHIVE            | YES     | Archive storage engine                                         | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| InnoDB             | DEFAULT | Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys     | YES          | YES  | YES        |
| PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA | YES     | Performance Schema                                             | NO           | NO   | NO         |
+--------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> [14.5.4 Converting Tables from MyISAM to InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/converting-tables-to-innodb.html)
>
> ...
>
> **Important**
>
> Do not convert MySQL system tables in the mysql database
>   (such as user or host) to the InnoDB type. This is an unsupported
>   operation. The system tables must always be of the MyISAM type.
>
> ...

Comment: Didnt checked that the tables were system tables. Good catch. +1

Comment: Thanks. But any clue, why is system tables kept in MyISAM format, when the default engine in MySQL 5.7 and 5.6 is InnoDB?

Comment: @kingsmasher1: From 5.5 InnoDB is the default engine and documentation is not very explicit on this point: `The \`mysql\` and \`information_schema\` databases, that implement some of the MySQL internals, still use MyISAM. In particular, you cannot switch the grant tables to use InnoDB.`. See [14.1.2 InnoDB as the Default MySQL Storage Engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-default-se.html).

Comment: Is this still valid as to the newest MySQL versions?

Comment: @W.M.: From MySQL 8.0, `... Data dictionary tables and system tables use the InnoDB storage engine unless otherwise indicated. ...`, see [5.3 The mysql System Database](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/system-database.html).

Comment: @wchiquito, I guess the same applies to latest versions of `MariaDB`. I am using latest version of `MariaDB`, but I have noticed that some tables in `mysql` still using `MyISAM`. Do you know of any built in command which would take care of migrating those tables to `InnoDB`?

Comment: @W.M.: I can't guarantee that it applies equally to MariaDB, the documentation of MariaDB isn't very explicit in this aspect, see [Converting Tables from MyISAM to InnoDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/converting-tables-from-myisam-to-innodb/). You can read the following error report: [System table in InnoDB format allowed in MariaDB could lead to crash](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-10775). Using MariaDB 10.3.7, I couldn't reproduce the error described in the error report.

Comment: Now I understand, seems that version 8.0 is pretty new. I guess the same would apply for MariaDB sooner or later. I expect that the Linux distribution upgrade of MariaDB would take care of any needed conversions in system table. Current in my system 10.0.34. I will be watching this.